# Switchpoint detection with probabilistic programming (pymc)

Tags: probability, markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc, change-point

I'm currently reading the [Probabilistic Programming and Bayesian Methods for Hackers](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers) "book". I've read a few chapters and I was thinking on the first Chapter where the first example with pymc consist of detecting a witchpoint in text messages. In that example the random variable to indicate when the switchpoint is happening is indicated with $\tau$. After the MCMC step the posterior distribution of  $\tau$ is given: [image]

Firstly what can be learned from this graph is that there is a propability of almost 50% that the switchpoint happend on day 45. Though what if there wasn't a switchpoint ? Instead of assuming there is a switchpoint and then trying to find it, I want to detect if there is in fact a switchpoint.

The author answers the question "did a switchpoint happen" by "Had no change occurred, or had the change been gradual over time, the posterior distribution of $\tau$  would have been more spread out". But how can you answer this with a propability, for example there is a 90% chance a switchpoint happend, and there is a 50% chance it happend on day 45.

Does the model need to be changed ? Or can this be answered with the current model ?

Comment: Mentioning the book author @Cam.Davidson.Pilon, who may have a better answer than mine below.

Answer (score 6):

SeanEaster has some good advice. Bayes factor can be difficult to compute, but there are some good [blog posts](http://stronginference.com/post/bayes-factors-pymc) specifically for Bayes factor in PyMC2.

A closly related question is goodness-of-fit of a model. A fair method for this is just inspection - posteriors can give us evidence of goodness-of-fit. Like quoted:

> "Had no change occurred, or had the change been gradual over time, the posterior distribution of $\tau$ would have been more spread out"

This is true. The posterior is quite peaked near time 45. As you say > 50% of the mass is at 45, whereas if there was no switch point the mass should (theoretically) be closer to 1/80 = 1.125% at time 45.

What you are aiming to do is faithfully reconstruct the observed data set, given your model. In [Chapter 2](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter2_MorePyMC/MorePyMC.ipynb), their are simulations of generating fake data. If your observed data looks wildly different from your artificial data, then likely your model is not the correct fit.

I apologize for the non-rigourous answer, but really it's a major difficulty that I haven't efficiently overcome.

Comment: Maybe unrelated to your answer, I'm just thinking aloud. Wouldn't it be possible to fit a sigmoid to the data and based on the beta parameter decide if the slope indicates a change or not. Maybe the threshold determining if there is a switchpoint can be learned from examples then.


Maybe this is also possible with the $\lambda$ parameters. If $\lambda$1 differs too much from $\lambda$2 there is a switchpoint else not. This could maybe also be done with a threshold that is learned from examples

Comment: For example, fit the model: $\lambda_1 p + \lambda_2 (1-p)$, where $p = 1/(1 + exp(-\beta t) )$? That would work I believe, and would allow for smooth transitions. You are correct that inference on $\beta$'s slope could determine if a switch point exists. I really like this, you should explore it more.

Comment: On the question of model fit, I'd add that posterior predictive p-values are one way of assessing fit. [See this paper](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall09/cos597A/papers/GelmanMengStern1996.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

That's more of a model comparison question: The interest is in whether a model without a switchpoint better explains the data than a model with a switchpoint. One approach to answer that question is to compute the [Bayes factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor) of models with and without a switchpoint. In short, the Bayes factor is the ratio of probabilities of the data under both models:

$K = \frac{\Pr(D|M_1)}{\Pr(D|M_2)} =\frac{\int\Pr(\theta_1|M_1)\Pr(D|\theta_1,M_1)\,d\theta_1}{\int \Pr(\theta_2|M_2)\Pr(D|\theta_2,M_2)\,d\theta_2}$

If $M_1$ is the model using a switchpoint, and $M_2$ is the model without, then a high value for $K$ can be interpreted as strongly favoring the switchpoint model. (The wikipedia article linked above gives guidelines for what K values are noteworthy.)

Also note that in an MCMC context the above integrals would be replaced with sums of parameter values from the MCMC chains. A more thorough treatment of Bayes factors, with examples, is available [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~kass/papers/bayesfactors.pdf).

To the question of computing the probability of a switchpoint, that's equivalent to solving for $P(M_1|D)$. If you assume equal priors across the two models, then the posterior odds of the models are equivalent to the Bayes factor. (See slide 5 [here](http://www.acritch.com/media/slt2011/plummer-bayes.pdf).) Then it's just a matter of solving for $P(M_1|D)$ using the Bayes factor and the requirement that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n P(M_i|D) = 1$ for n (exclusive) model events under consideration.